# Click on a tag remove current raw in data table?

Tags: jquery

I am go for the show list of user using jquery datatable.and for the delete i have  set one a tag.and i am click on a tag i want to remove this raw from the table but i am not getting success. i am try some wave but not find parent tag and remove raw. here below this my code =>

This is my html =>

```
function LoadUsers(UserDdlFilter) {
  oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    tableTools: {
      'aButtons': [{
        'sExtends': 'xls',
        "sButtonText": "Download Excel"
      }, ]
    },
    "oLanguage": {
      "oPaginate": {
        "sPrevious": '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        "sNext": '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
      },

      "sSearch": "",
      "sProcessing": "<div class=\"cssload-container\" style=\"display:block;left:0%\" id=\"Loader\"><ul class=\"cssload-flex-container\"><li><span class=\"cssload-loading\"></span></li></ul></div>"
    },
    "lengthMenu": [
      [100, 1000, 5000, 10000],
      [100, 1000, 5000, 10000]
    ],
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "processing": true,
    //"dom": '<"top"ifl>rt<"bottom"p>',
    //"sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetUserList", "Users")',
    "sAjaxSource": 'Users/GetUserList?UserDdlFilter=' + UserDdlFilter,
    "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

      $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function(json) {

        document.getElementById("TotalUsers").innerHTML = json.TotalUsers;
        fnCallback(json)

      }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        //window.location.reload();
      });
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
      $("th:first").removeClass("sorting_asc");
      $("[class='Toggle-Button']").bootstrapSwitch();
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      orderable: false,
      targets: -1
    }],
    //"order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
    "aoColumns": [{
        "mData": "SrNo"
      },
      {
        "mData": function(source) {
          var resObj = {
            'ProfileImage': source.ProfileImage
          }
          return resObj;
        },
        "mRender": function(resObj) {
          var res = "";
          if (resObj != "") {
            var res = '<img src="' + resObj.ProfileImage + '" width="80" />';
          }
          return res;
        }
      },
      {
        "mData": "Name"
      },
      {
        "mData": "UserName"
      },
      {
        "mData": "Email"
      },
      {
        "mData": "PhoneNo"
      },
      {
        "mData": function(source) {

          var resObj = {
            'UserId': source.UserId
          }
          return resObj;
        },
        "mRender": function(resObj) {
          var html = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Delete_"' + resObj.UserId + '" onclick="DeleteUser(' + resObj.UserId + ')"><i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete User" class="fa fa-trash delete"></i></a>';

          return html;
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

this is my ajax call =>

function DeleteUser(UserId) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete")) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Users")';

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: {
    UserId: UserId
  },
  cache: false,
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.Result == "Success") {
      $('#myDataTable a#Delete_' + UserId).remove(); // i want here remove raw from the table on click a tag.
      $("#Loader").hide();
    } else {
      $("#Loader").show();
    }
  },
  error: function(reponse) {
    alert("error : " + reponse);
  }
});
}
}
```

Comment: Show you full html code. Where is row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have checked it, 
Here you go.

```
$('a#Delete_' + UserId).parents('tr:first').remove();
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help and please up 1 vote on my post idk any one user minus give me